# Reset NSUserDefaults if user cancels preferences panel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSWindow designed in Interface Builder which is showing all preferences to my App. All selections and textfields are bound to an NSUserDefaultsController. How can I discard all changes the user made when he cancels the dialog via a cancel button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Apple documentation for the NSUserDefaultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSUserDefaultsController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaultsController/revert:) shows some great methods, like`revert:`and `revertToInitialValues:`, which seems like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick, it resets the defaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:[NSDictionary dictionary]  forName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
```